# codeigniter pagination using ajax jquery

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, pagination

How to create pagination in codeigniter using Ajax? I know how to create simple pagination, but am struggling how to create this thing using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to stumble on this great project which turns your pagination into Ajax without much coding to your PHP files.

If you don't mind "Scroll to load", you can try out http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin

Even if you don't prefer scroll to load, it should give you some idea behind ajax pagination.